# How to move multiple lines to join another in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have thousands of lines of code in notepad++ that looks like the following:

```
befwwef  
:efiewmfewfm

krtmhrthmrt  
:ewfowoofowwwwww

fwmfemwf  
:wefiwenweniewnf
```

I need each of the two lines to join together so they look like this:

```
ewfwfwefew:ewiekdmdm
```

I'd like to kill the space in between those lines as well so all of the lines look like this but without the space:

```
ewfwefewewf:ffewwefwe  
fweef:ewfwefwefewf  
ewfwefwefewfw:wefweffwfewfw  
ewfwewef:eweewewwe
```

I'm sure this is an easy fix for someone but i only started using the find and replace feature in notepad++ today, i'm trying to find each line with a ":" on them but i'm not sure how to keep the colon and then backspace the line to join the other.

Appreciate any help i've searched for a simple fix but it looks too complicated for me at the moment!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regular expression mode of the find & replace (you need to opt for that search mode).

In find, use:

```
\s*:\s*
```

[`\s` matches space, tab, newlines and `*` means 0 or more times.]

And in the replace, use:

```
:
```

Shouldn't be too hard.